# How do I apply sharpening via compositing to several movie clips simultaneously in my video editing project?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I’ve assembled a sequence of movie clips in Video Sequence Editor.  What’s the most efficient way of applying the same sharpening filter in composting to several clips at once?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no sharpening filter in Blender.

In general, if you need to add an effect filter to several strips, add an Adjustment Layer over all strips and add an effect to that.

For modifiers, there is a button in the sidebar/Strip Menu to copy the modifiers from the active strip to all selected strips.